# Handling a Database in setOnCLickListener(... method

Tags: android, database, eclipse

In my project I want to put a Reset Button for my Database (only one entry, 4 different information I need to update to follow the user's progression in a quiz)

The problem is that I need to launch the method initDB() inside this Listener:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button reset = null;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.raz);

        DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(this);
.
.
.
        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            dbGestion.open();
            dbGestion.initDB("Alex"); 
            dbGestion.close();
        }

    });
```

It says that I can't refer to a non-final variable (dbGestion) inside a class defined in a different method. But it doesn't work with dbGestion as a final variable..

Any idea?

Comment: If your database is that simple, you might be better off using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) instead of a SQL database

Comment: The thing is that I have to change the content very often (to keep a sign of already answered questions, completed level, ...) . The tutorial I have followed do not speak of such an use for SharedPreference. Is it convenient for that?

Comment: "But it doesn't work with dbGestion as a final variable.." Why doesn't it work?  You can also make `dbGestion` a field variable, like `reset`, if you are going to use it in multiple methods.

Comment: If the order of questions is sequential, you can use SharedPreference to store the last answer index. If the questions can be answered in any order, it gets a lot less practical. Update frequency is not really a problem for both approaches

Comment: My bad, I though it lead me to a "Force close", but I tried in another activity so declaring it as a final variable works... dbGestion is my Database Manager, so I don't know if it's right to declare it as a field variable

Comment: Actually I asked this question because I had the same problem to check answers in an EditText, and I had to declare it public to make a editText.getText(); inside the Listener.

But I still have a force close on my second activity. Is it enough to put  DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(this); and dbGestion.open(); to have access again to the database?

Comment: If I understand you: yes, putting `DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(this);` and `dbGestion.open();` in each Activity where you want to interact with your database is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options to use:

1. A field variable in MainActivity
2. A final variable in `onCreate()`
3. A field variable in the anonymous OnClickListener
4. A local variable inside `onClick()`

For instance:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    // (1) DBGestion dbGestion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        // (1a) dbGestion = new DBGestion(this); // Instantiate field variable
        // (2) final DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(this);
        reset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // (3) DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(MainActivity.this);
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                // (4) DBGestion dbGestion = new DBGestion(MainActivity.this); or new DBGestion(v.getContext());
                dbGestion.open();
                dbGestion.initDB("Alex"); 
                dbGestion.close();
            }
        });
```

(There are more options, but they start to get eccentric.)  None of these methods is inherently right or wrong, they all have their strengths and weaknesses.  The choice depends on if you use `dbGestion` anywhere else and your personal preference.

Comment: Which way should I use for my second activity (general activity for each question)? I want to check a value inside onCreate (to check if this question was already answered) and then update this value inside a Listener (This way I know the question was answered)

Comment: Since you only want to access your database in `onCreate()` and an `OnClickListener` inside `onCreate()`, I recommend #2 (or #1).  Do you understand why `dbGestion` must be `final` in approach #2?

Comment: I though it was because you musn't have a variable that can change because of another task inside the listener, but now that you showed me the other ways, no....